# Documentation comment for loop variable in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation

I know that we can use

```
/// index variable
var i = 0
```

as a documentation comment for a single variable.

**How can we do the same for a loop variable?**

The following does not work:

```swift
var array = [0]
/// index variable
for i in array.indices {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
var array = [0]
for /** index variable */ i in array.indices {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Background:**

The reason why I don’t use "good" variable names is that I’m implementing a numerical algorithm which is derived using mathematical notation. It has in this case only single letter variable names. In order to better see the connection between the derivation and the implementation I use the same variable names.

Now I want to comment on the variables in code.

Comment: is it strongly needed ? you can write a comment for the whole for-loop block the 1 who reads is supposed to be a developer and should get it plus the comment for the looped array should be enough

Comment: I suspect you can't. The for...in syntax is pretty much self-documenting, but in your example `i` isn't an index variable, it's a variable that receives the entries from your collection.

Comment: To be honest, such a comment actually makes the code less readable. A comment should explain and document. Pointing out that `i` in a `for` loop is an index is far too obvious to clutter with such a comment as "index variable". Readers of your code would benefit from a non-documentation comment that explains, at a higher level, what the code in the loop does and explains any non-obvious algorithm logic or possible constraints, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your comment! Please see my updated question

Comment: @Qbyte But if the comment is simply "index variable" then there is no point. Any programming with a basic understanding of the programming language already knows that the variable is an index variable.

Comment: @rmaddy This is just a simple example. I only want to document this variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `///` is primarily intended for use of documenting the API of of a class, struct, etc. in Swift.

So if used before a `class`, `func`, a `var`/`let` in a class/struct, etc. you are attaching documentation to that code aspect that Xcode understands how to show inline. It doesn’t know how to pickup that information for things inside of function since at this time that is not the intention of `///` (it may work for simple var/let but not likely fully on purpose).

Instead use a simple `//` code comment for the benefit of any those working in the code however avoid over documenting the code since good code is likely fairly self explaining to anyone versed in the language and adding unneeded documentations can get in the way of just reading the code.

This is a good reference for code documentation in Swift at this time [Swift Documentation](https://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’m implementing a numerical algorithm so it is very difficult to have a self documenting program. Please see my updated question.

Comment: As stated in my answer Xcode only sees `///` as a documentation comment when placed before a class, struct, enum, func, or class/struct let or vars, etc. It doesn't really look for `///` inside of a function (it may work in a few case but not likely from any real intent), it just isn't built that way (nor do any doc generators that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

I woud strongly push back on something like this if I saw it in a PR. `i` is a massively well adopted "term of art" for loop indices. Generally, if your variable declaration name needs to be commented, you need a better variable name. There are some exceptions, such as when it stores data with complicated uses/invariants that can't be captured in a better way in a type system.

I think commenting is one area that beginners get wrong, mainly from being misled by teachers or by not yet fully understanding the purpose of comments. Comments don't exist to create an english based, psuedo-programming language in which your entire app will be duplicated. Understanding the programming language is a minimal expectation out of contributors to a project. Absolutely no comments should be explaining programming language features. E.g. `var x: Int = 0 // declares a new mutable variable called x, to the Int value 0`, with the exception of tutorials for learning Swift.

Commenting in this manner might seem like it's helpful, because you could argue it explains things for beginners. That may be the case, but it's suffocating for all other readers. Imagine if novel had to define all the English words they used.

Instead, the goal of documentation to explain the purpose and the use of things. To answer such questions as:

- Why did you implement something this way, and not another way?
- What purpose does this method serve?
- When will this method of my delegate be called?

## Case Study: `Equatable`

For a good example, take a look at the [documentation of `Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable)

Some things to notice:

1. It's written for an audience of Swift developers. It uses many things, which it does not explain such as, arrays, strings, constants, variable declaration, assignment, `if` statements, method calls (such as `Array.contains(_:)`), string interpolation, the `print` function.
2. It explains the general purpose of this protocol.
3. It explains how to use this protocol
4. It explains how you can adopt this protocol for your own use
5. It documents contractual requirements that cannot be enforced by the type system.

   > Since equality between instances of Equatable types is an equivalence relation, any of your custom types that conform to Equatable must satisfy three conditions, for any values `a`, `b`, and `c`:
   >
   > - `a == a` is always true (Reflexivity)
   > - `a == b` implies b == a (Symmetry)
   > - `a == b` and `b == c` implies `a == c` (Transitivity)
6. It explains possible misconceptions about the protocol ("Equality is Separate From Identity")

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’m implementing a numerical algorithm so it is very difficult to have a self documenting program. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Qbyte Ah, I've had this conundrum before. Do I stick with the single char variable names from the algorithm's mathematical specification (which makes verification easy, but understanding difficult), or do I use names better for programming (which makes understanding easy, but verification hard). I don't know how to handle it well.

Comment: @QByte Last time I ran into this issue, I sided with the "stay consistent with the math" approach, which ultimately bit me in the ass, because there were other papers that covered the same algorithm as what I had implemented, but with different variable names, which led to a lot of confusion (particularly for common names like ∂, x, i, n).

Comment: Thank you very much for your further comments! In the future I will also use good programming names in these "mathy" cases. Then I don’t need this specific documentation variable documentation as much.